# Android How to scan for hidden access points

Tags: android, performance, linux-device-driver, wifimanager, access-point

how can i do programmatically scan for hidden Wireless Access Points, in android ?
`getScanResults` give me only visible Access Points , but i need to discover hidden too.

When programmatically scanning Wi-Fi networks (using `WifiManager.startScan()` and `WifiManager.getScanResults()`), when the SSID broadcast is disabled on an access point and the access point has never been connected to the device, the ScanResult element for this access point does not appear in the list of access points returned.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10305

Answer (score 0):

If you could scan hidden Access Points, what would be the point of hiding them?

EDIT: Instead of being a smartass, I will try to to be at least a little bit helpful. The reason nobody has implemented this yet is because to sniff networks without connecting with them, your wireless card (or chip in the case of phones) needs to support [monitor mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode). Almost no phone manufacturers have unlocked this feature, and it's up to them to enable monitor mode in the drivers. Don't count on it though.

Comment: i want to make application like inSSIDer , but for android, and i need this option.

Comment: @RomanKredentser *i want to make application like inSSIDer* then you need to find out how inSSIDer does it.

Comment: inSSIDer for windows, for inSSIDer application for android cost money , and i dont thinks its have this option