# Does Android ScanResults report hidden networks with empty SSIDs?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009538/android-how-to-scan-for-hidden-access-points) stating that hidden networks cannot be scanned for. However, when I perform a scan I get back networks that have empty SSIDs. I understand that there are ways of scanning for hidden networks so hiding SSIDs is really not a good security technique as stated [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28653/debunking-myths-is-hiding-your-wireless-ssid-really-more-secure/). So I was wondering if the ScanResults do report hidden networks and indicate this by returning empty SSID values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We set up a hidden network and found the answer to this issue. Maybe this will help someone else. The answer is no. Android scans do not detect hidden networks. Results with empty SSIDs are not hidden networks! (I don't know what they are called besides networks with no SSID name).